# Rearranging values in 3 columns in SQL Server in descending order

Tags: sql-server

I want to rearrange the values in 3 columns (`a, b, c`) in descending order and I have written the logic below. The logic works for most of the times but not working properly when "c" is the highest number

```
SELECT 
    CASE
       WHEN a > b AND a > c THEN a 
       WHEN b > a AND b > c THEN b 
       ELSE c  
    END AS a,
    CASE
       WHEN b > c AND a > b THEN b 
       WHEN c > a AND c < b THEN c 
       ELSE a 
    END AS b, 
    CASE 
       WHEN b > c AND a > c THEN c 
       WHEN a < c AND a < b THEN a 
       ELSE b 
    END AS c
```

Comment: Are the columns nullable? If so should nulls sort high or low?

Comment: May want to consider making some of those `>=` instead of `>` - if a = b and both are greater than c, your first case will still sort c as the largest value.

Comment: Yes the columns are nullable. When creating the table if one value is null the other 2 must be null.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this would be

```
SELECT ca.a,
       ca.b,
       ca.c
FROM   t
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN val END) AS a,
                           MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN val END) AS b,
                           MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN val END) AS c
                    FROM   (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY val) rn,
                                   val
                            FROM   (VALUES (a),
                                           (b),
                                           (c)) v1(val)) V2) ca
```

If the columns are nullable this will sort nulls first.

To sort them at the end you could change the `ORDER BY` to `ORDER BY CASE WHEN val IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, val`

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b04e/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use just column comparison and not Martin Smith's solution you can do it by adding equalities + adding the 2 missing cases for the middle values:

```
SELECT 
    CASE
       WHEN a >= b AND a >= c THEN a 
       WHEN b >= a AND b >= c THEN b 
       ELSE c  
    END AS a,
    CASE
       WHEN b >= c AND a >= b THEN b 
       WHEN b >= a AND c >= b THEN b 
       WHEN c >= a AND b >= c THEN c 
       WHEN c >= b AND a >= c THEN c 
       ELSE a 
    END AS b, 
    CASE 
       WHEN b >= c AND a >= c THEN c 
       WHEN a <= c AND a <= b THEN a 
       ELSE b 
    END AS c
```

You can test this in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dd91b/1)